# Problem downloading "not free" programs from Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center, proxy, downloads, free

I bought "Quick 'n Easy Web Builder" in Ubuntu Software Center on 15 march, 2013 and it worked OK after unlocking it with my license key.

Now I have replaced my computer (with Ubuntu 12.04LTS) but I cannot download the program anymore: when I try to start the download in Ubuntu Software Center I invariably get the message:

`"Condizioni d'uso - Unable to load page - Problem occurred while loading the URL https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/tos/plain/ - Cannot resolve proxy hostname()"`.

The same problem seem to happen with all paid programs, while I can download free ones without problems.

Thank you! Paolo